# Line 21, in <module> image_id = annotation['image_id'] TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Tags: python, deep-learning, omr

```
import json
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D


with open('deepscores_train.json', 'r') as f:
    train_data = json.load(f)


with open('deepscores_test.json', 'r') as f:
    test_data = json.load(f)

train_x = []
train_y = []

for annotation in train_data['annotations']:
    # 获取图像ID
    image_id = annotation['image_id']

    # 查找与当前注释匹配的图像
    image = next((i for i in train_data['images'] if i['id'] == image_id), None)
    if image is None:
        continue

    # 从图像文件中加载图像数据
    with Image.open(image['file_name']) as img:
        img_data = np.array(img, dtype='float32')

    label = annotation['category_id']

    train_x.append(img_data)
    train_y.append(label)

train_x = np.array(train_x)
train_y = np.array(train_y)

test_x = []
test_y = []

for annotation in train_data['annotations'].values():

    image = next((i for i in train_data['images'] if i['id'] == annotation['image_id']), None)
    if image is None:
        continue

    with Image.open(image['file_path']) as img:
        img_data = np.array(img, dtype='float32')

    label = annotation['category_id']

    # 将图像数据和标签添加到测试数据集中
    test_x.append(img_data)
    test_y.append(label)


test_x = np.array(test_x)
test_y = np.array(test_y)


model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:])))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=128, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_x, test_y))

model.save('music_model.h5')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\md\model.py", line 21, in 
image_id = annotation['image_id']
~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

I tried to train the model with DeepScores' data.But line 21 keeps getting an error, so I hope someone can help me change the code

Comment: Could you post a section of deepscores_train.json? Specifcally referring to annotations.

Comment: It looks like `annotation` is a str, not a dict.  You might want to examine the actual structure of `train_data` more closely. It looks like `json.load()` isn't converting it as expected.

Comment: '1134151': {'a_bbox': [766.0, 1486.0, 787.0, 1513.0], 'o_bbox': [787.0, 1486.0, 766.0, 1486.0, 766.0, 1513.0, 787.0, 1513.0], 'cat_id': ['17', '150'], 'area': 302, 'img_id': '833', 'comments': 'instance:#00006d;'} 
This is a section of deepscores_train.json